# Catch all at the end of " for in"

Tags: python, regex

Is it possible to have a "catch all" statement that affects everything that hasn't been added by a `for match in re.findall` statement already.

```
for submission in submissions:
    print (submission.url)
    for match in re.findall(".+imgur\.com+",submission.url):
        NonFilteredImgurImageList.append(submission.url)
    for match in re.findall("gfycat\.com",submission.url):
        GfycatUrlList.append(submission.url)
    else:
        NonStandardUrlList.append(submission.url)
```

I tried with above, but that didn't work.

Is there a way to make it work or a better way to set it up (I plan to add more regex searches as time goes on).

Comment: What exactly is "catch all"? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Also note that `".+imgur\.com+"` is not what you want, it matches strings like `"http://imgur.commmmmmmmm"`.

Comment: Can a `submission.url` contain more than one url? and if so do you want to add each one individually or just the submission (as you have, effectively duplicating in case of multiple urls).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you need a regex. In fact, if those `re.findall` calls actually contained multiple results, it would append duplicates of corresponding `submission.url` strings. Just use `in`.

```
for submission in submissions:
    print(submission.url)
    if 'imgur.com' in submission.url:
        NonFilteredImgurImageList.append(submission.url)
    elif 'gifycat.com' in submission.url:
        GfycatUrlList.append(submission.url)
    else:
        NonStandardUrlList.append(submission.url)
```

If regex matches were actually desired here, you would use something like the following:

```
for submission in submissions:
    i = re.findall(expression1, submissions.url)
    g = re.findall(expression2, submissions.url)
    if i:
        results['imgur'] += i
    elif g:
        results['gfycat'] += g
    else:
        results['failures'].append(submissions.url)
```

Comment: I suppose technically one should use `urllib` parsing to avoid misclassifying URLs like `http://nonstandard.example.com/i/look_what_i_found_on_imgur.com`, but that's really beyond the scope of the question being asked.